# mypy isn't detecting uninitialised attributes

Tags: python, mypy

This code checks with `mypy`'s default invocation:

```
class A:

  myattr: str


class B(A):
  otherattr: str
```

but both `A().myattr` and `B().myattr` raise an attribute error: `AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'myattr'`

Is there a way to get mypy to report this?

This is with Python 3.7.2, mypy 0.670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is currently no.

There is some discussion about adding this as a feature here:

https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4019

But doesn't look like there's been any updates recently. Perhaps worth commenting there if you have a strong use case for doing it, and what error you'd expect to see, i.e. would you want the error to be that you're accessing an initialised variable or that the variable isn't initialised in the class init or new constructors?

Answer (score 1):

I found I could get most of what I wanted (in my real world use case) by defining a `Protocol` rather than a regular superclass: `mypy` does detect uninitialised attributes defined there.